# Discord.py adding a member to a created channel permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get this part of my code to create a channel and add the user to the channel to see and type but can't post images.

```py
        elif str(reaction) == "❔":
            remove_id(member.id)
            guild=member.guild
            overwrites = {
                guild.member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
            }
            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name='application')
            
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{member.name}-interview', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
            channel_name = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name=channel)
            channel_id = channel.id
            view_channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
            embed1=discord.Embed(title="Verification Request", description=f"Verification request of {member.mention}", color=int(hex_color, 16))
            embed1.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
            embed1.add_field(name="How did you find this server?", value=found, inline=False)
            embed1.add_field(name="How old are you?", value=age, inline=False)
            embed1.add_field(name="Tell us about yourself?", value=about, inline=False)
            embed1.add_field(name="What are you looking to get out of this server?", value=seek, inline=False)
            embed1.set_author(name=member.name)
            embed1.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {member.id}")
```

The error I get is:

```
Ignoring exception in raw_reactian_add 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-package/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event 
        await coro(•args, ••kwargs) 
    File "root/Treehouse/cogs/verification.py", line 273, in on_raw_reaction_add 
        guild.member: discord.PernissionOvervrite(read_nessages=False) 
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'member'
```

I am struggling to add the member to the channel and set the permissions to send_messages=True, read_message=true, and post_images=False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [valid permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Permissions) as `post_images` is `attach_files`.

[create_text_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) states the overwrites are

> A dict of target (either a role or a member) to PermissionOverwrite to apply upon creation of a channel. Useful for creating secret channels.

guild.member does not exist because guild is a [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild) object. Use `member` instead as stated by the quote.

```py
elif str(reaction) == "❔":
            remove_id(member.id)
            guild=member.guild
            overwrites = {
                member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True,  send_messages = True, attach_files = True)
            }
           
            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name='application')
            
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{member.name}-interview', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
            channel_name = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name=channel)
            channel_id = channel.id
            view_channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
            embed1=discord.Embed(title="Verification Request", description=f"Verification request of {member.mention}", color=int(hex_color, 16))
            embed1.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
            embed1.add_field(name="How did you find this server?", value=found, inline=False)
            embed1.add_field(name="How old are you?", value=age, inline=False)
            embed1.add_field(name="Tell us about yourself?", value=about, inline=False)
            embed1.add_field(name="What are you looking to get out of this server?", value=seek, inline=False)
            embed1.set_author(name=member.name)
            embed1.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {member.id}")
```